# Avoid <colgroup> / <col> HTML tags to alter <thead> and <tfoot> rows?

Tags: html, css, colgroup

Is there a way to limit/restrain the field of "operation" of styles defined in `<colgroup>` / `<col>` HTML tags.

Given the following table:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col align="center" />
        <col align="center" style="background-color: lightgrey;" />
        <col align="center" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
            <th>Column C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.a</td>
            <td>1.b</td>
            <td>1.c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.a</td>
            <td>2.b</td>
            <td>2.c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the `background-color: lightgrey;` not to be applied to the "Column B" cell (Second `th` in `thead`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always apply a style to that cell in particular, or style the whole `<tr>` for your header row.

http://jsfiddle.net/QQ7LJ/

```
 <tr style="background-color:white;">
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>Column B</th>
        <th>Column C</th>
 </tr>
```

in short: no, there is no way to "limit" css, it will match every available target, and styling your `<col>` will match the entire column.  In order to get different styling, you need to overwrite it somehow, the easiest way being to explicitly style the ones that dont match the general style.

Edit, you can also do this in a stylesheet block, by using CSS3 selectors `:nth-of-type` and scoping your selector to the `<tbody>` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/QQ7LJ/1/

```
tbody td:nth-of-type(2) {
 background-color: lightgrey;   
}​
```

and the changes to your HTML (everything else is the same)

```
<colgroup>
    <col align="center" />
    <col align="center"/>
    <col align="center" />
</colgroup>
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to limit `<col>` but thanks for the answer. Problem with overriding `background-color` CSS directive is that setting it to `transparent` on the `<td>` makes no difference in the final render because `<col>` seems to be just underneath that `<td>`.

Comment: `:nth-of-type` is indeed a good practical solution (at least in my case).

Comment: You should use colgroup for irregular headers.  How is this an irregular header? You have one colgroup of 3 columns, and then every tbody tr is 3 td's each.  That's regular. See: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/ for examples of tables with irregular headers.